# Stop android app from closing

Tags: android, sms, broadcast

I'm using the BroadcastReceiver to receive SMS messages with my app, and then edit a database based on what the message says. The app works fine when it's open, but If I leave it on for a long period of time and it automatically closes the app will force close when it receives a message (I think the BroadcastReciever is still working, but the rest of the app has closed). IS there any way to keep the app from closing, or resuming it when it receives a text message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want the receiver to be persistent you should consider using a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead of a standard `Activity` for your application. [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle)s that exist in a standard activity are considered to be a foreground service *only* when processing `onReceive` as soon as the execution returns the `Activity` resumes its normal process priority and can be terminated by the system as needed.

From: [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle)

> **Process Lifecycle**
>
> A process that is currently executing a BroadcastReceiver (that is, currently running the code in its onReceive(Context, Intent) method) is considered to be a foreground process and will be kept running by the system except under cases of extreme memory pressure.
>
> Once you return from onReceive(), the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active, and its hosting process is only as important as any other application components that are running in it. This is especially important because if that process was only hosting the BroadcastReceiver (a common case for applications that the user has never or not recently interacted with), then upon returning from onReceive() the system will consider its process to be empty and aggressively kill it so that resources are available for other more important processes.
>
> This means that for longer-running operations you will often use a Service in conjunction with a BroadcastReceiver to keep the containing process active for the entire time of your operation.

For more information on creating a service:

> **Developer Guides**
> For a detailed discussion about how to create services, read the [Services developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).

Comment: To convert it to a service do I just need to change "activity" to "service" in the XML file?

Comment: @TrentWalls No, I have updated my answer with a link from the Services page of the Android documentation that has some information and guides on creating a Service. It should be noted that a Service and an Activity are fundamentally different units of functionality.